# How can I tell the toolchain that xcode uses to find a file in a particular location?

Tags: c++, xcode

I have a file located in `/opt/X11/include/GL/glx.h`. I want Xcode to "see" this location when I  compile my C++ program so that don't get a file not found error when I include a statement like this

```
 #include <glx.h>
```

How can I tell xcode to look in this location? Alternately (and maybe better) where can I move this file so that xcode "sees" it? Where does xcode "look" for include files?

Answer (score 0):

You can add `/opt/X11/include/GL` to your target's header search paths. It's in the target's build settings. [See here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/XcodeConcepts/Concept-Targets.html) for more details on setting the target settings.